# Mulesoft connector for deduplication based on id from REST GET API

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Coming for Zapier world to Mulesoft, Zapier has a REST poll connector which polls REST GET APIs and can deduplicate records by Id to find newly created records and stream those records periodically.

I am just curious if such connector exists in MuleSoft.

Comment: yes. you should read about watermarking and poll scopes in mule. the two links below will help you understand them.

Comment: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/data-synchronizing-made-easy-with-mule-watermarks/

Comment: https://www.jerney.io/mulesoft-data-sync-watermarking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Idempotent Message Validator component does the same for MuleSoft
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/idempotent-message-validator